# Ant subtask to utilize different Java Version

Tags: java, ant

We have a step in our build which relies upon an old JDK to run, as the process does not work with Java 6. It's not generating bytecode, just doing some modifications to text files.  Updating the process would take longer than we have, and due to the nature of the process it seems quite okay to just leave this step of the build process utilizing the old JDK.

The real question is, can it be done?

Comment: Are you using the Ant java task to run that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

Tweak the Java6 JVM settings to be compatible with the process when calling it using parameters on the Ant task:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

OR

Execute the java command binary in the legacy JDK with an `exec` Ant task:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Comment: If you are 'exec'ing the task, can also split the tasks you want to run in the separate java vm into a separate ant script. Exec blocks, so you can call it just like a normal task. Might not be the prettiest solution, but it gets my +1.